# Need to find Ratios and Smallest accurate number with python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this exercise but I got stuck in implementing the right procedure to find the values that I need. Could someone tell me if I am doing right and if not what I can do to improve it please. The exercise requests:

### Q5: After how many tosses, your MLE estimate is within $[0.97001, 0.96999]$

You analyze a new coin, where there are 1 million tosses of the same coin where the true    value is  0.97
Here "1" stands for "head"

- report the minimum number that satisfies this

```
global smallest_accurate_num

np.random.seed(15) #a fixed random seed so that everyone gets the same results
n = len(sample_2) #total coin tosses
print("Length of sample_2:", n)
sample_h_t = np.where(sample_2 == 1, 'H', 'T')#turn 1 into H
heads_n = np.count_nonzero(sample_2 == 1)#number of heads
print("The number of total heads is:", heads_n) 
print(ratios)
a = np.zeros(n) #a lot of zeros
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = bernoulli.rvs(0.9, size = pow(10,5)) #this will generate a value of "1" with probability 0.9, and "0" otherwise
    
    if a[i] >= 0.96999 and a[i] <= 0.97001:
        smallest_accurate_num += 1
        print("We needed just", smallest_accurate_num, "toss")   
    elif a[i] < 0.96999:
        smallest_accurate_num += 1
        print("We did", smallest_accurate_num, "tosses and did not reach the range yet")
     
    

small_accurate_n = ...
```

Anyway, I did some progresses but now I am getting an error about the variable a which says:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7144/3667000441.py in 
10 a = np.zeros(n) #a lot of zeros
11 for i in range(n):
---> 12     a[i] = bernoulli.rvs(0.9, size = pow(10,5)) #this will generate a value of "1" with probability 0.9, and "0" otherwise
13
14     if a[i] >= 0.96999 and a[i] <= 0.97001:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Your call to bernoulli.rvs is returning an array with 100,000 elements, because you set that by the `size` keyword.  `a[i]` can only take a single number.

Comment: How could I fix it?